# ViewController does not have member named ""

Tags: ios, swift

This is a common question, however, going through the questions that are out there, I can't find a solution to my problem. I have essentially been trying to get UISearchController working on my own with the help from "Search Controller" project on git hub. Everything is working except I keep getting the ViewController does not have member named "searchArray"

My PlacesViewController is a UIViewController class with the following member

```
var searchArray = [String]()
```

I have the following in my searchDisplayController

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlacesViewController2") as  ViewController
```

I get the error when I enter the following code. It is not recognizing the member searchArray for some reason.

```
viewController.searchArray
```

I am not sure why I can't access this member in the other swift file.

Thanks

Comment: I think we need to see more code to help, mainly how your viewcontroller class is setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    .instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlacesViewController2")
        as  ViewController
```

With:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    .instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlacesViewController2")
        as  PlacesViewController
```